# Android: Which method is best for putting Json into sqlite database

Tags: android, json

I have an activity that recieves json string,

```
  public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "cars";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "car";


public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "Brand";
public static final String COL_3 = "Question";
public static final String COL_4 = "Answer";


String CarBrand=getInent().getStringExtra("BRAND");
String Json=getIntent().getStringExtra("car_QuestionsAnswersPair");
```

and value stored in json is :    {Model: "Corolla", Transmission: "Auto","Color":"Red"}

[image]

Inside database helperclass:

```
public boolean insertData(String brand, String question, String answer) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(COL_2, brand.toLowerCase());        
        contentValues.put(COL_3, question.toLowerCase());
        contentValues.put(COL_4, answer).toLowerCase());
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        return result != -1;
    }

     public Cursor getAllData(String BrandName) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME+" WHERE Brand='"+BrandName+"'", null);

            return result;
    }
```

now if someone sends me a json string    {Model: "Corolla", Transmission: "Auto","Color":"Red"} how am i supposed to save it in database ? and there can be more than 3 details for each car. not only model, transmission and color. so each car can have different numbers of questions.I am competely new to json.